# Llamar valores de una clase mediante un valor obtenido en un jtextfield

Tags: java

me urge una ayudita...

Tengo un jframe en el cual llamo otro jframe, con este capturo en un jtexfiel un determinado texto.

Lo que necesito es que ese jtexfiel llame los valores de otro jframe.

por ejemplo: la clase uroanálisis tiene color, aspecto, densidad y ph
quiereo que al obtener el texto uroanálisis en mi jtexfield yo pueda llamar sus valores.

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] para ver de que forma tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y tengan más chances de recibir una buena respuesta. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora. Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Sin poner tu código no se te puede dar una buena respuesta. Te recomiendo mirar la documentación de los JTEXTFIELD [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--)

El método sería getText().

Answer (score 1):

No puedo ayudarte realmente sin ver el código, porque no llegue a entender lo que necesitas. 
Pero según lo que pusiste creo que podrías usar una función callback, que se invoque cuando pedis los datos del JTextField.

Por si no tenes bien claro de que se trata aca te dejo una buena [explicacion](https://fernetjs.com/2011/12/creando-y-utilizando-callbacks/)

La otra interpretación es que quieras obtener los valores ingresados en ese JTextField al presionar por ejemplo un JButton. En ese caso es un poco mas sencillo, tenes que usar la funcion getText() del JTextField en cuestion. 
Te aconsejo leer la documentación, esta todo muy claro ahi.